# Small & Balanced family of sets

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, ramsey-theory, extremal-combinatorics

I have the following problem:

> Let $\epsilon >0$, and $[n] = \{ 1,2,...,n\}$ the set of positive integers up to $n$.
>   There exists a family of subsets $\mathcal{F} \subseteq 2^{[n]}$, such that
>
> 1. $|\mathcal{F}| = O(n)$, and
> 2. for every non-empty $S \subseteq [n]$, one has
>
> $$ \epsilon |\mathcal{F}|  \hspace{0.2cm} \leq \hspace{0.2cm}
>  | \{ F \in \mathcal{F} : |F \cap S| \mbox{ is odd } \}|
>  \hspace{0.2cm} \leq \hspace{0.2cm} (1-\epsilon)|\mathcal{F}| ?$$

Maybe it is also a "famous" problem, maybe a trivial one, I don't know.

Do you know something about this?

Comment: This is certainly untrue when $\epsilon >\frac12$. Does this need to be true for all $0<\epsilon\le \frac12$? Or just a single $\epsilon$ in this range?

Comment: It is sufficient that it is true for some $\epsilon >0$.